# Joining by location and by fields simultaneously using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, spatial-join

ArcMap 10.4.0.5524 for Desktop. No internet connection.

I have points with street names and lines with street names. I would like to join the points and the lines (giving the attributes of the lines to the points) spatially, but also contingent upon a matching street name. The issue is sometimes the points are closer to the line with the wrong street name (for example, at an intersection). So the join would look be "the closest line that also matches the street name". I can't just use the street name because there are many lines with the same street name (different segments of the same road, for example).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Google was unhelpful.

I know Python, but have little experience with geospatial analysis using Python (I just used Geopandas for the first time today).

Comment: Generate near table with few neighbours. Transfer street names to this table for points and for streets. Delete no matching records. Delete duplicates for point  OID.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about that tool.

Comment: Perhaps self-answer and accept solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Generate Near Table (Analysis)" tool.

My way of getting the correct match was to then join the attributes of the original tables to the Near Table and then use Python to loop over the data and keep only the closest line with a matching street name.